# Bug with PyPy + gzip?

Tags: python, gzip, pypy

A very simple case:

```
import gzip
import cStringIO

s = 's' * 1000
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb').write(s)
buf.tell()
```

Under Python 2.7, `buf.tell()` returns `29` and the contents of the buffer can be unzipped to reconstruct the original string.
Under PyPy 5.8.0, `buf.tell()` returns `10` and the contents are corrupt and cannot be unzipped.

This is also true when using the `StringIO` module instead of `cStringIO`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe flush or close the `GzipFile` instance?

Comment: What is `buf` here?

Comment: @Błotosmętek I've updated the code sample.

Comment: @kichik You were correct. Apparently, you need to flush. I replaced the `gzip.GzipFile...` line with a `with` statement, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like kichik said, you need to close the file.  In PyPy files are not as promptly closed as in CPython.  For proof, the following code also prints `10` on CPython:

```
import gzip
import cStringIO

s = 's' * 1000
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb')
f.write(s)
print buf.tell()
```

The difference with your code is only that the GzipFile object is stored in a variable `f`, which is still alive when `buf.tell()` is called; it is waiting for more data before it finishes to write the gz data to the `buf` file.  The proper fix is to close the file, with either `f.close()` or the `with` statement.  This is mentioned in the first paragraph of [this section in the CPython difference page.](http://pypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies)